# Convert date strings like 20 July 2017 to epoch and compare in Linux

Tags: linux, date

I am using ksh, and  have a text file with several lines of following content. I am trying to compare the date part to current date and find the difference in days and then output the "Server" and "Qmgr" part of the file to another file

Here is my input file

```
server1        :       Qmgr1      :       20 July 2017
server2        :       Qmgr2      :       22 July 2017
server3        :       Qmgr3      :       22 Dec 2015
```

if the difference between the current date and the date in the file is less than 90 days, then expected output should be

server3        :       Qmgr3

What could be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: This question is about programming, and you don't even say what language you want to use. I'm assuming bash.

Comment: re the date part, GNU `date` seems to understand "20 July 2017" just fine: `/bin/date +%s -d '22 July 2017'` gives `1500674400`.

Comment: If it's ksh, then it's probably AIX and that may well not have gnu tools.

Comment: It works using date command. how do I do this within a shell script to go through every line , convert to epoch, compare to current date and output the Qmgr part of the file if the difference is more then x days.

Comment: You would need to provide a sample of your input file, and a sample of what should be provided. You also need to [edit] your question to include this new update. Or ask a new question and link it to this.

Comment: updated to be more clear on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  This script reads the files listed on the command line or standard input and prints the server and qmgr values for each line where the date is 90 days or less in the future.

```
#!/bin/sh

# also works with ksh, bash, zsh

now=$(date +%s)
ninety_days=$(( 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 ))

cat "$@" |
while read server colon qmgr colon2 qdate
do
    future=$(date +'%s' -d "$qdate")
    if [  $((future - now))  -lt  $ninety_days  ]
    then
        echo "$server $colon $qmgr"
    fi
done
```

Explanation:

Store the number of seconds between "the epoch" (1970-01-01 UTC) and the current time in the variable `now`:

```
now=$(date +%s)
```

Calculate the number of seconds contained in 90 days:

```
ninety_days=$(( 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 ))
```

Convert the date which was read from the last 3 fields of the record into the number of seconds between the "epoch" and that date.  Store in the variable `future` (so-named for clarity when comparing to the variable `now`):

```
    future=$(date +'%s' -d "$qdate")
```

Subtract `now` from `future` to get the number of seconds between the current date and the date in the file.  We've calculated the number of seconds contained in 90 days, so we can just compare that to the difference between `future` and `now`.

```
    if [  $((future - now))  -lt  $ninety_days  ]
```

Comment: Robert sorry for the late reply. This worked for me. Thank you.. Can you elaborate "FUTURE" and logic within if condition please

Comment: Sure, please see the edited answer.